# Saving Information Android

Tags: android, listview

I am still fairly new to android and trying to learn day by day. I am trying to create a simple test application that you register for with an email/password to learn how to use save data from users.The app I am making is going to be simple, once they register and login, the user can search through a list of items I created on my MainActivity, and when they click on the listview item it will open a new activity. On the new activity, there will be a favorites button that I want to be able to click on and it will store that listview item information onto a favorites fragment I created and it will show the user a list of movies the user saved as favorites.

I am just trying to find out the best way I can do this. I have looked into SQLite and Firebase, hoping someone can explain to me which way would be the best way to approach this and maybe link me to a tutorial if possible.

Also the adding favorites to a listview item, if any one has a tutorial on that. I have already created my main listview and using Intents take the information and pass it to the new activity. It just clicking on the favorites button and saving the information into a new listview I do not know how to do, especially for when the users closes and re-opens the app the favorites will still be there.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To save favourite items in a new ListView you have to store the information somewhere. If you're using SQL, then store the Primary Key value in a favourites table that you can then use to find the corresponding information from the initial ListViews table.

If you are using firebase then each item in your list should have a unique key. Save that key and then when loading the favourites ListView, use the saved key to get the key's child data.

To summarise:
Store in a favourites table/branch the items the user selects as favourites and use that table/branch then to populate the favourites ListView.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could consider doing is storing your favorites using SharedPreference. The logic that would then follow is you have each row in your list view be an object that has an ID. Anytime a user favorites that object you save it into a set and store that set into SharedPreference that are corresponding to the current account username. You can then retrieve that set and show only the favorite objects for the user later on.

As for the SQLite vs Firebase question, I have not worked with Firebase yet, most of my interactions have been custom API calls. Having said that, I think SQLite would be a nice way to handle this as it would keep things easy and give you a good understanding of both sides of the equation.

Check out this tutorial. This very next one also covers SQLite:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SwAvFYMsXE